Grounding of the shielded segment 6a
There is an unshielded UTP 5e network. There is a vertical line between the floors (upper, middle, lower). A new network is being installed on the ground floor.
Since a large load of multimedia was expected in the future, I decided to lay a new vertical thicker. But instead of category 6, UTP overlooked and laid 6a STP. That is, the server is upstairs, the Internet gateway on the middle floor is the existing UTP 5e vertical. And a new 6a STP has hung from the middle to the bottom (it is also planned to reach the top).
Question: How to properly ground this segment? And integrate it with an existing unshielded network? On patch panels in floor nodes? And the connection between the patch panel and the switch - which should be given to an unshielded network?

See Shielded and unshielded twisted-pair cable revisited

"If STP cable is combined with improperly shielded connectors, connecting hardware or outlets, or if the foil shield itself is damaged, overall signal quality will be degraded. This, in turn, can result in degraded emission and immunity performance. Therefore, for a shielded cabling system to totally reduce interference, every component within that system must be fully and seamlessly shielded, as well as properly installed and maintained."

"Category 6a" (lowercase 'a') isn't a thing. Generally, category 6 cabling is unshielded (UTP), including cat 6A for 10GBASE-T. Vertical cabling should be fiber, with twisted pair being limited to horizontal distribution.
That said, shielded cabling must be properly grounded on both sides, usually on the panels.
Mixing shielded and unshielded cabling within a link does not work well and should be avoided, with the exception of (short) patch cables on the ends. Instead, you should put a switch between shielded and unshielded runs.

Thank you! Is it possible to connect a shielded cable to a switch, which then connects to unshielded segments? Then should I ground the patch panels with shielded cable and the switch?

Clarification: the shielded cable is connected to a grounded panel, and from it to the switch via a patch cord. Should the patch cord be shielded? Should the switch be grounded?
The switch then links the shielded and unshielded segments.

No, a (short) patch doesn't need to be shielded. The switch is usually sufficiently grounded by the rack (which MUST be properly grounded), but local regulations or company policies may mandate otherwise.

6/6A are real. "7" was never defined. Yes, it exists in shielded flavors. The shielding has nothing to do with 6 or 6A, which is about signal quality. Within "shielded" there are different methods... foil, braid, individual pair shielding, ... You really need a well versed professional to deal with it. In 99% of installs, shielding is unnecessary. (in 30+ years, I've only installed shielded cable once... in a radio station. and it was 5e)
